# Denting a sphere into a plane

Tags: modifiers, displacement, surface-deform

[image]

I would like this plane to deform around this UV sphere — specifically, in a way that makes it look like a sphere was violently rammed into the plane, causing a wide (not completely sphere-shaped) dent If it deforms the entire plane slightly that's even better.

I would furthermore like the depth of this dent to scale proportionate to the sphere's position to the plane. For instance, if the sphere isn't touching the plane, no dent, if the sphere is slightly touching the plane, a small dent, if the sphere's middle lines up with the plane, a large dent. I would not like this dent to adhere to the surface of the sphere; I would rather that the sphere "tug" on nearby vertices as well as those whose lines it intersects with.

What set of modifiers or operators could allow me to do this, if any?

Comment: Soft body or cloth physics.

Comment: @Nathan Are there any specific settings you recommend I use those with? I'm unfamiliar with them. Also, I doubt the cloth physics would work; I don't want the plane to behave like a cloth, I want it to behave like a rigid sheet which has had a dent beaten into it.

Comment: Let me amend that: sculpting the dent is better.  But physics are more like what you're describing-- more procedural, less artistic.  I'm not really interested in making a dent with them myself, which is why all I'm doing is letting you know what kind of things to *become* familiar with in a comment, rather than a full answer.

Comment: @Nathan Aye, thanks.

Comment: It also depends a little on what material the ground should be made of. Is the dent like a dent in metal, (wet) sand/snow, concrete/ice or elastic/pudding? If you want to try a Cloth sim, make a collision object (=a plane with a hole in the middle, hidden for render), put another plane on it (=the cloth object with a pin group that pins the outer area). Finally, make a sphere with collision fall into the (invisible) hole to create the dent.

Comment: @Blunder Think of it as a tank shell hitting a steel plate and deforming it in a certain direction somewhat; updating the question with that. I will do my best to try your advice regarding cloth simulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For kicks I went the Shrinkwrap route:

[image]

I sub-divided the plane surface into sufficient segments and assigned the center group of vertices to vertex group "Group".

I then used the Skrinkmap modifier to the target Sphere, and found that project, Outside Surface worked best.  Note that I had to "play" with the Z-distance between the two, and added a slight offset to keep the two visually separated (plane always on top of sphere) -- you may not need this is you want to hide the sphere from rendering.

If you want, then try Applying the S.R. and Surface Deform to the sphere.  This might allow you to play more with moving the sphere around which can cause extra wrinkle-distortions to appear (creases).

[image]

Comment: This is almost perfect. Do you know a way to increase the distance that the deformation falls off at? Everything in your answer works but I'm getting a distinctly sphere-shaped dent rather than a sort of wider one.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE - first, Unbind the SurfaceDeform on the Plane.  Then, for the sphere, add a SimpleDeform modifier, and try *Stretch* mode, Z axis, -0.2.  This will create a more elliptical shape (spread the Shrinkwrap out a bit).